# Databricks Auto Loader file notification mode in Azure Premium storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I want to use Databricks AutoLoader to read a stream of files, the volume of the data is high so I want to use file notification mode (when I used directory listing mode the latency was bad), but it seems I need a "storage queues" which is unavailable in Azure Premium storage,  when I tried to run the following code I got the error msg: UnknownHostException: <storageName>.queue.core.windows.net

```
val manager = CloudFilesAzureResourceManager
  .newManager
  .option("cloudFiles.connectionString", "XXX")
  .option("cloudFiles.resourceGroup", "XXX")
  .option("cloudFiles.subscriptionId", "XXX")
  .option("cloudFiles.tenantId", "XXX")
  .option("cloudFiles.clientId", "XXX")
  .option("cloudFiles.clientSecret","XXX")
  .option("path", "abfss://XXX@ZZZ.dfs.core.windows.net/test") // required only for setUpNotificationServices
  .create()

// Set up a queue and a topic subscribed to the path provided in the manager.
manager.setUpNotificationServices("XXX")
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/auto-loader/file-notification-mode#permissions-azure

there is a way to use file notification mode in  Azure Premium storage?

Answer (score 0):

Using Auto loader to scale autoloader to ingest millions of files. The options **use notification** allows you to choose directory listing mode detecting new files.

Please provide the necessary permission to create cloud resource. Configure `cloudFiles`, if you use the notification is set to true.

```
cloudFiles ={
    "cloudFiles.subscriptionId" :"<subscription_Id>",
    "cloudFiles.connectionString" :"<connectionString_Storage_account>",
    "cloudFiles.format":"csv",
    "cloudFiles.tenantId":"<tenantId>",
    "cloudFiles.clientId":"<client_ID>",
    "cloudFiles.clientSecret":"<Client_Secret>",
    "cloudFiles.resourceGroup":"<Resource_group_name>",
    "cloudFiles.useNotifications":"yes"
}
```

For more information on configuring [**autoloader**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6960/databricks-auto-loader-with-schema-evolution/) with data bricks follow this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNG-5uRY4o8). it has a details explanation about **read** and **write** streaming data on the autoloader.

Comment: I tried that but I got the same exception (see below), the main reason for the problem is that "storage queues" is not available in Azure blob storage premium, so creating the ResourceManager in Azure fails.
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: 
 at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:87)
 at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:220)
.......
 at com.databricks.sql.aqs.autoIngest.AzureEventNotificationSetup.setUpAqsQueue(AzureEventNotificationSetup.scala:110)